# How can i get currency symbols from currency code in iphone?

Tags: cocoa, currency, symbols

I have get currency code (Eg: USD, EUR, INR) from webservice response. I need to show the currency symbols for the corresponding currency code. If the currency code is USD, i need to show $, if the currency code is EUR i need to show €. How can i do this? Please suggest any idea or sample code to do this. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This code works charm in my project. I will share this to you all.

```
NSString *currencyCode = @"EUR";
    NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:currencyCode] autorelease];
    NSString *currencySymbol = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol value:currencyCode]];
    NSLog(@"Currency Symbol : %@", currencySymbol);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this code works as desired. It shows correct currency symbols only for eur and usd. For all the other currencies it shows  first character for currency code.

Comment: This code seems magical, it's not clear why it does what it is doing. If you change the third line so that it prints `[locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol]`, the output prints `Currency Symbol : ¤`.

Comment: this code works correctly only for EUR and USD, others don't work well for me.

Comment: Also second line is wrong. Strange that it works. Should be: `NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale]`. The `currencyCode` is not equal to the locale identifier.

Comment: This is not the correct answer, as mentioned earlier localeIdentifier does not match currencyCode

Answer (score 16):

Swift 4 version

Finding locale by currency code:

```
let localeGBP = Locale
                  .availableIdentifiers
                  .lazy
                  .map { Locale(identifier: $0) }
                  .first { $0.currencyCode == "GBP" }
print(localeGBP?.currencySymbol) // £
```

Formatting currency

```
if let locale = localeGBP {
  let formatter = NumberFormatter()
  formatter.numberStyle = .currency
  formatter.locale = locale
  let result = formatter.string(from: 100000) // £100,000.00
}
```

---

Edit:

Why `.lazy`? Without it the loop would run over *all* the locale identifiers and return the first one which matches. That's about 700ish identifiers, and if the first one is the one you want then you have wasted creating 699 Locales :) With `.lazy` in there it automatically stops at the first matching one. In my case it reduces the number of times through the loop from 710 down to 22 when converting "GBP". This isn't important if you are only doing this once, but if you're doing this a number of times (i.e. over an array of symbols) then it's an easy way to get a bit more efficiency.

Comment: why finding a local and iterating? you can just create a local NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "GBP")

Comment: @carmen_munich  NSLocale(localeIdentifier:) takes a locale identifier string (eg. "en_GB"). Not the currency code.

Comment: In my opinion this is the correct answer, I've use the code above and worked perfectly for what I wanted: Validating a String representing a currency (ISO Code format) is valid within them all. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't produce reliable results under Swift 5.1. Searching for a locale with the currency code of `USD` returns a locale with the identifier `es_EC`.

Comment: @TonyArnold actually that's correct `es_EC` is the Spanish locale for Ecuador. Ecuador happens to use US Dollars.

Comment: This does not work for all locales and codes. The correct way is to start with the valid user locale and override the currency code only. That will work for all locales and codes (see my answer further below for code)

Answer (score 14):

This code is what you are looking for though not very efficient because of loop for locales. Still it works *correctly* for all currency codes, not just for eur or usd. Hope this will help you.

```
- (NSLocale *) findLocaleByCurrencyCode:(NSString *)_currencyCode
{
        NSArray *locales = [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers];
        NSLocale *locale = nil;

        for (NSString *localeId in locales) {
                locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:localeId] autorelease];
                NSString *code = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode];
                if ([code isEqualToString:_currencyCode])
                        break;
                else
                        locale = nil;

        }

        return locale;
}

- (NSString *)findCurrencySymbolByCode:(NSString *)_currencyCode
{
        NSNumberFormatter *fmtr = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        NSLocale *locale = [self findLocaleByCurrencyCode:_currencyCode];
        NSString *currencySymbol;
        if (locale)
                [fmtr setLocale:locale];
        [fmtr setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        currencySymbol = [fmtr currencySymbol];
        [fmtr release];

        if (currencySymbol.length > 1)
                currencySymbol = [currencySymbol substringToIndex:1];
        return currencySymbol;
}
```

Use it this way:

```
NSString *currencySymbol = [self findCurrencySymbolByCode:currencyCode];
```

Comment: This code has some nasty flaws: If `NSNumberFormatter` decides not to place the currency symbol first in the output, you'll get back an incorrect result. If the currency symbol happens to occupy more than a single UTF-16 codepoint, it'll get chopped off and be invalid

Comment: Improve it and allow others to use. Is not this site about that? ) and thanks.

Comment: Indeed. Improved answer has been posted.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind here, when you searching for NSLocale with currency code, is that, for example France and Netherlands have save currency symbol - €, but it's written 1,00 € in France and €1,00 in Netherlands. So you'll get the whatever NSLocale is spotted first.

Comment: The equivalent for this did NOT work in Swift. I had to port your code over in an Objective-C bridge and for some reason that worked. Unreal. Thank you.

Comment: See my answer below for efficient way to do this

Answer (score 10):

`NSLocale` will happily tell you the currency symbol used by a particular locale:

```
[locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol];
```

It'll also tell you the currency code:

```
[locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode];
```

So all you have to do now is look up the locale that corresponds to a given code. There's no built-in method (that I'm aware of) to do this directly, so loop through all the known locales and pick the one that matches. @Umka's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11526694/28768) has a good example of this in the `-findLocaleByCurrencyCode:` method.

You could optimise the process by building your own lookup table, rather than iterating through all locales each time. You may need to handle the possibility of duplicate currency codes too, which would require some heuristic for deciding which is the most likely locale.

Answer (score 5):

Building on code from @Mike Abdullah and @Umka, here are some functions in Swift.

```
func findCodeAndSymbolForAllLocales() {
    let locales = NSLocale.availableLocaleIdentifiers()

    for localeId in locales {
        let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: localeId)
        if let code = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode) as? String,
            let symbol = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol) {

            print("\(code) \(symbol)")

        }
    }
}


func findCurrencySymbolByCode(currencyCode:String) -> String? {

    guard let locale = findLocaleByCurrencyCode(currencyCode) else {
        print("locale for \(currencyCode) is nil")
        return nil
    }

    return locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol) as? String
}

func findLocaleByCurrencyCode(currencyCode:String) -> NSLocale? {

    let locales = NSLocale.availableLocaleIdentifiers()
    var locale:NSLocale?
    for localeId in locales {
        locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: localeId)
        if let code = locale!.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode) as? String {
            if code == currencyCode {
                return locale
            }
        }
    }

    return locale
}
```

Comment: there were a lot of changes to this code over the time. but xcode was able to fix all the issues. works great

Answer (score 3):

```
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;

NSString * localeIde = [NSLocale localeIdentifierFromComponents:@{NSLocaleCurrencyCode: currencyCode}];
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:localeIde];

NSString * symbol = formatter.currencySymbol;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to start with a valid locale (e.g. the user current locale) and then override the currency code.  Simple and efficient and allows you to use the newly constructed locale to configure a currency formatter in order to display a string according to the user's locale preferences:

```
NSLocale* locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
if (_currencyCode) {
    NSMutableDictionary* components = [[NSLocale componentsFromLocaleIdentifier:locale.localeIdentifier] mutableCopy];
    components[NSLocaleCurrencyCode] = _currencyCode;
    locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:[NSLocale localeIdentifierFromComponents:components]];
}
return locale.currencySymbol;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
```

this is for US currency style

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    //[numberFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@"Rs"];        
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:@"en_IN"];
```

This is for indian

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please tell me clearly? I can't understand your answer. Don't mistake me. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Swift

```
let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: currencyCode)
let currencySymbol = locale.displayName(forKey: .currencySymbol, value: currencyCode) ?? currencyCode
print("Currency symbol: \(currencySymbol)")
```

Comment: as @cynichniy-bandera mentioned before this code works only for EUR and USD.