# How would I get a list of world currencies and their corresponding symbols (i.e. $, £, ¥, €, etc.) in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, currency

In my app I want to populate a table that contains all (or most) of the currencies in the world into a table view. On the left I want the currency code (i.e. USD, CAD, etc) and on the right I want the corresponding currency symbols (i.e. $, £, ¥, €, etc.).

Using the iOS SDK, how can I get a list of both currency codes and symbols such that I can populate into a table view where a user can select their preferred currency?

Comment: [NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/ISOCurrencyCodes). What are your trying to do with it? Your question doesn't really give details.

Comment: I edited my question to provide more detail.

Comment: Wicked. I wish I could post this as an answer, but use: `NSString *currencySymbol = [self findCurrencySymbolByCode:currencyCode]` as shown in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11526694/2535467)